# Responsive SVG image path not available

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, schema

Using following line of code, the application on which I am working is creating resized image url.

```
string responsiveImageUrl = SiteConfiguration.MediaHelper.GetResponsiveImageUrl(Url, aspect, widthFactor, containerSize);
```

eg: *mysitename/en/media/agriculture_tcm1010-123038_w320_h198_n.svg*

But this image is not available, if I see remove the `_w320_h198_n`, the image url which is `mysitename/en/media/agriculture_tcm1010-123038.svg` displays an image. And this issue is only with `.svg` type. Is it not possible to resize an svg image or the issue is specific to SDL Tridion only?

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Looks like you're using DXA.NET. Which version?

Answer (score 1):

Resizing is not applicable for SVG images, since these are Scalable Vector Graphics; you don’t have to change the image to render it at any size.